# MongoDB mapReduce mapper function

Tags: mongodb

In this mapper function:

```
var mapper = function()
{
emit(this.gender,1)
}
```

What does 1 signify?

Comment: You could look at the [mapReduce documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) from the MongoDB site. It will tell you that a "mapper" must `emit` a "key" and a "value". In this case `1` is the value. You don't post a reduce function here, but I guess the context by the original developer is to "count" by "gender". There is also likely a better way to do this. But you are not posting the full code or asking the real question here.

Comment: @NeilLunn your comment should be an answer.

Comment: My comment is "speculation", though informed speculation based on what content that is posted and not nearly enough information to be a clear question. With a little clarity it is at best a duplicate question, therefore no need to answer something clearly answered before. A link to the documentation so the OP can "work out" what someone before them has coded should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It adds `1` (value) to key `gender`.

In the reduce function, you would sum up those.

Example:

Map:

```
male x 1
male x 1
female x 1
         ^---- this is the "1" you ask for
```

Reduce:

```
male x2 (sums "male x 1" + "male x 1")
female x1
```

Comment: Bit of a long winded way to not actually make it clear that the person who wrote the code probably just wants to "count" by gender don't you think? Doesn't even really answer the question asked even though that was poorly worded in itself.

Comment: @NeilLunn Semantically, you count the values. Technically, you sum them. You are absolutely free to post your own answer if you don't like mine.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce is a recursive mechanism, you then need a basis in your recursion.

For instance if you have this data :

```
{"name" : "Tim",     "country" : "USA",      "age" : 15}
{"name" : "Sandra",  "country" : "USA",      "age" : 18}
{"name" : "Alex",    "country" : "France",   "age" : 19}
{"name" : "Zhong",   "country" : "Taiwan",   "age" : 19}
{"name" : "Tom",     "country" : "USA",      "age" : 20}
{"name" : "Marc",    "country" : "France",   "age" : 20}
{"name" : "Hao",     "country" : "Taiwan",   "age" : 12}
{"name" : "Jennifer","country" : "USA",      "age" : 15}
{"name" : "Jean",    "country" : "France",   "age" : 17}
{"name" : "James",   "country" : "USA",      "age" : 17}
{"name" : "Peter",   "country" : "USA",      "age" : 20}
{"name" : "Jorge",   "country" : "Portugal", "age" : 20}
```

If you want to know the statistics by ages you can apply this mapReduce function :

```
function(){
    return db.Data.mapReduce(

            // Fonction MAP
            function(){
                emit(this.age,{count:1});
            },

            // Fonction REDUCE
            function(key,values){
                var reduced = {count:0};
                values.forEach(function(val) {
                    reduced.count+=val.count;
                });
                return reduced;
            },

            // Configurations
            {
                out : 'Stats'
            });
}
```

This diagram explains you what can happen theoretically during this process, the emit function set the value as a basis for recursivity : 
[image: Sample for the execution of a MapReduce Job]